# Closed subspaces of $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

I would like to prove that the almost-everywhere constant functions, and the functions whose integral is 0 are closed subspaces of $L^2(0,1)$.
It's readily seen that they are subspaces. I'm finding some difficulties trying to show that they are closed.

For example, with the constants:

I take a convergent sequence of almost-everywhere constant functions $f_n$. It converges to a function $y$. I know that for each $\epsilon>0$ i can find a $n_\epsilon$ such that for $n>n_\epsilon$ I have

$\int\limits_{0}^{1}|f_n(x)-y(x)|^2 dx<\epsilon$

Well It's obvious that $y$ is a constant a.e. but how can I show it formally?
Same problem for the convergent sequences of functions $u_n$ such that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}u_n(x)dx=0.$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By "almost everywhere constant", you mean there is a $c$ such that $\{ x : f(x) \neq c\}$ is a null set?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the constants:
   prove that the subspace is complete. In an Hilbert space, this is equivalent to being closed, and in this case it is easier.
2. For the null integrals subspace:
   show that $\int f_n\to \int f$.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, use that any $L^2$-convergent sequence has a subsequence that converges almost everywhere.

Alternatively, you can use that any finite-dimensional subspace of any normed vector space is closed. This essentially follows (in your case), because

$$\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}_+, x \mapsto \Vert x \cdot \chi_{[0,1]} \Vert_{L^2}$$

gives a (necessarily equivalent) norm on $\Bbb{R}$.

For the second part, use that the functional

$$L^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, f \mapsto \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$$

is bounded and hence continuous (use Cauchy-Schwarz with the constant $1$ function), so that the kernel is a closed subspace.

Comment: For the first problem how would I use the subsequence that converges almost everywhere?

Comment: @Monolite: Say $f_n \to f$, where the $f_n$ are almost everywhere constant. We want to show that $f$ is also almost everywhere constant. By switching to a subsequence, we get $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost everywhere, say on $N^c$ for a null-set $N$. Now, for each $k$, there is a null-set $N_k$ and a constant $c_k$ with $f_{n_k} (x) = c_k$ for all $x \notin N_k$. Note that $N_0 := N \cup \bigcup_k N_k$ is a null-set. For $x \notin N_0$, we have $f_n (x) = \lim_k f_{n_k} (x) = \lim_k c_k =: c$, where we see in particular that the limit $\lim_k c_k$ exists. Hence, $f_n$ is a.e. constant.

Comment: Thank you! is there a typo here $f_n (x) = \lim_k f_{n_k} (x) = \lim_k c_k =: c$ and in the last line where instead of $f_n(x)$ there should be $f(x)$?

Comment: @Monolite: Yes, these are typos. Unfortunately I cannot edit the comment anymore, so I will just leave it that way instead of retyping everything.

Comment: No need you have already been very Kind. Thanks again.